# PandaDoc view and edit Document Before Send to Recipient

Tags: javascript, sdk, pandadoc

From last few days I am exploring PandaDoc APIs for esignature purpose which is requirement for my project.

So far I have used following APIs.

```
create Document api     : https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents
send Document api       : https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents/{{document_id}}/send
get Status of document  : https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents/{{document_id}
Create a Document Link for session Id : 
   https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents/{{document_id}}/session
```

Using above APIs I could send a document to recipient and ask him/her to sign it.
Also I can make use of field tags to place fields like signature or textfield. So that when recipient receives a document they can edit  textfield etc. So far this use case works perfectly fine.

What I am looking for is to preview and edit document before I send it to recipient. Is there any way via API to achieve document edit before its being sent to the recipient.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about this pandadoc? https://developers.pandadoc.com/docs.  It has a web API and a javascript SDK.  No Java.  Please adjust the tags on this question to match what you are actually asking.

Comment: Please adhere to the comments from @StephenC